# Importing publish settings file from azure storage using power shell

Tags: powershell, azure

I want to import publish settings file in powershell which is kept in azure storage. But it is not working I am trying the below command. If I use my local file system it works...

Import-AzurePublishSettingsFile -PublishSettingsFile "https://.blob.core.windows.net/scripts/MyFile.publishsettings"

How do I resolve this ?

Comment: You realy shouldn't store the publish settings file within your blob storage. However, it looks like, you import a `ps1`file instead of a `publishsettings`file. Maybe you can use the `Add-AzureAccount` cmdlet?

Comment: I corrected by file.. thanks but I want to run PowerShell script through automation and I cant use Add-AzureAccount.. I don't want to create login dependency

Comment: Add-AzureAccount is the way to go, there is no reason why you can't use it for automation...

Answer (score 1):

Simply put, you can't do that because the cmdlet expects the publish settings file location to be on a local computer (and that's why when you use local file system, it works).

If you want to use a publish settings file stored in blob storage, you must download it first on the local computer (you can use [`Get-AzureStorageBlobContent`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/f6f939e1-1296-436a-b034-7b933cd67f36) cmdlet for that) and then provide the path where you downloaded the file to this cmdlet.